# Перевод символа в набор битов

Tags: c

У меня есть набор из 7 символов. Мне нужно вытащить из каждого символа номер ячейки в кодировке ascii и преобразовать номер ячейки в бинарный вид, чтобы в итоге у меня получилось 56-битный бинарный массив, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Строка в C и так представляет собой именно массив байт. Так что 7 байт строки это и есть 56-битный бинарный массив

Comment: Но мне нужно работать с этими битами, к тому же я не смогу разделить 7 байт на две равные части

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под «номером ячейки»?

Comment: значит возьмете 3 байта как есть а от четвертого возьмете либо старшую часть `b >> 4`, либо младшую `b & 0x0F` только массив unsigned char объявляйте, что бы проблем со знаком не возникло

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Ну, вроде всё тривиально.

```
struct bit_array_builder
{
    unsigned char* array;
    unsigned char* current_byte;
    size_t current_bit;
};

void init_array(bit_array_builder* p_builder, size_t max_bits)
{
    size_t max_bytes = (max_bits + (CHAR_BIT - 1)) / CHAR_BIT;
    p_builder->array = calloc(max_bytes, sizeof(unsigned char));
    p_builder->current_byte = p_builder->array;
    p_builder->current_bit = 0;
}

void add_to_array(unsigned int value, size_t number_of_bits, bit_array_builder* p_builder)
{
    while (number_of_bits > 0)
    {
        size_t remaining_bits = CHAR_BIT - p_builder->current_bit;
        size_t bits_in_chunk = remaining_bits > number_of_bits ?
            number_of_bits : remaining_bits;
        unsigned char partial_mask = (1 << bits_in_chunk) - 1;
        unsigned char partial_value = value & partial_mask;
        *(p_builder->current_byte) |= partial_value << p_builder->current_bit;
        p_builder->current_bit += bits_in_chunk;
        if (p_builder->current_bit == CHAR_BIT)
        {
            p_builder->current_bit = 0;
            p_builder->current_byte++;
        }
        number_of_bits -= bits_in_chunk;
        value >>= bits_in_chunk;
    }
}
```

И можно тестировать:

```
int main()
{
    bit_array_builder b;
    init_array(&b, 56);

    add_to_array(-1, 7, &b);
    add_to_array(0, 7, &b);
    add_to_array(-1, 7, &b);
    add_to_array(0, 7, &b);
    add_to_array(-1, 7, &b);
    add_to_array(0, 7, &b);
    add_to_array(-1, 7, &b);
    add_to_array(0, 7, &b);

    // на моей системе CHAR_BIT == 8
    for (int i = 6; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int bit = 7; bit >= 0; bit--)
            printf("%u", (b.array[i] >> bit) & 1);
        printf(" ");
    }
}
```

Выдаёт:

```
00000001 11111100 00000111 11110000 00011111 11000000 01111111
```

Answer (score 1):

Здесь есть два подхода

первый подход создать структуру и объединение

```
struct bit_field
{
uint32_t bit00:1;
uint32_t bit01:1;
....
uint32_t bit56:1;
uint32_t bit_rezerv:8;
};
union union_field
{
 struct bit_field;
 unsigned char symbol[7];
}__attribute__((packed));
```

записываете данные в массив symbol и оперируете битами в структуре

Второй подход создать набор define для оперирование битами

```
#define BIT_00           0x01
#define SET_BIT_00(f)    (f | BIT_00)
#define UNSET_BIT_00(f)  (f & (0xFF^BIT_00))
#define CHECK_BIT_00(f)  (f & BIT_00)
```

обрабатывать каждый символ по отдельности